# Delphi - TCustomControl - can it show dotted rectangle when got focus?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm coding an tExCustomControl, which in turn, I use to derive other custom controls. Assuming I have a tExButton inherited from tExCustomcontrol, I wonder how can I make the base class tExCustomControl show the dotted rectangle, when issuing a SetFocus to the derived class tExButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the overridden `Paint` method for the control, call [`DrawFocusRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162479.aspx) if the control has the focus.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Actually, I used Canvas.DrawFocusRect (aRect) to avoid the HDC parameter. Anyway, it works fine.

Comment: That sounds fine. Just a call to `DrawFocusRect` passing `Canvas.Handle` I guess. Comes to exactly the same thing. Using the canvas method is the clean way in VCL code.

Comment: @David Heffernan Can I removed dotted rectagle from dbgrid cell?